# The same loop generates different results

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why first the first loop generates expected results, but the second, although is the same loop generates empty list?

```
y = ["I am ok", "We are there", "Contraction: I've I'm won't"]
y1 = [(word for word in text.split(" ")) for text in y]

print("First:\n")
for i in y1:
    print(list(i))


print("\nSecond:\n")
for i in y1:
    print(list(i))
```

Results:

```
First:
['I', 'am', 'ok']
['We', 'are', 'there']
['Contraction:', "I've", "I'm", "won't"]

Second:
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: If you're planning to iterate twice, turn your generator expression into a list comprehension.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension link for the detailed usage n differences of generator vs comprehension expressions

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I didn't know that generators are one pass only. Thanks to the answers now I know. Correction is very simple. Second line shoud be: y1 = [[word for word in text.split(" ")] for text in y]